# How to call instance method from within class method?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to call instance method from class method. But I am getting error. I have tried below code:

```
  static func sendRequest(urlString: String, param: NSDictionary){

        if param.allKeys.count != 0{

             self. performPostRequest() //--Getting error

        }else{

             self. performRestRequest() //--Getting error
        }

 }

  func performRestRequest(){

        //--Some lines of code
   }

  func performPostRequest(){

        //--Some lines of code
   }
```

Please let me know, what is the correct way to call the methods type methods?

Sharing the error line from code where TMCommunicationUtil is Class name
[image]

Comment: You didn't let us now about your initiateGetRequest method (parameters etc.)

Comment: I haven't used a lot of static funcs but if I consider other languages, I am pretty sure you'd have to initiate `self` to something like: `let object = self.init()` and then use that variable to call the methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send an instance method, then you need *an instance*. There's no way around that.

If your class method wants to call an instance method, then it is quite possible that either the instance method should be a class method, or the class method should be an instance method. So have a look at that and maybe change your design.

Otherwise, your class method must create an instance, or get an instance from somewhere, and send the instance method to the instance.